# Text processor - How to recover a week ago version of a file?

Tags: microsoft-word, data-recovery, version

I am very desperate. I was producing a monograph and today when I went to index it I find that many sections got delete. I wrote those about a week ago.

Please suggest a way to find a version of the document where that part of text was still present! I am thinking is using file recovery software to try to find a temporary copy that was deleted which had the text in question.

Text editor is Word 2003.

Comment: That's why backups are important. There's effectively zero chance of recovery after the fact. Your time is probably better spent redoing the work and planning frequent (preferably automated) backups in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I've just found a file with part of the text. I've never said it was an easy task, but it's possible. That's why i've asked here in SU, there's plenty of gurus who have been thru something similar and found a way.

Answer (score 1):

I used a keyword-based sector search on the whole hard disk, it had a little chance to recover at least the clear text of my document. If you used the xml-based file format (.docx), your chances are better.

I am sorry but it is a system administrator forum, not a user forum. Sorry if I don't go into the "and next click with the right button" details, especially if also I don't know them.

It is a "superuser", also sysadm-forum, and for a system administrator were enough to find and to learn what he needs based on this info.

Comment: > I used a keyword-based sector search on the whole hard disk. Well, that really tells the OP what to do! And yet your "answer" attracted two upvotes. I wonder why.

Comment: I too. I think they found it interesting. Mostly I try to say at least the technical direction even if I can't give a perfect answer - third persons can it be useful. Check my other messages to see. At the beginning it happened that I wrote 20-30 messages without an upvote. And mostly I am searching for new questions without accepted answer.

Comment: TVM for your reply!

Comment: I would like to know how to do it more detailed

Comment: Start googling for "data rescue with keyword-based secotr search" on google! A "hexa hard disk editor" were a good idea I suggest.